# Get my taskbar back

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I just ran this command on a windows 10 computer:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
```

I used to run it on windows 7 computers and it would simply get rid of the taskbar, I used to find pretty cool and interesting.

Then I always run

```
explorer
```

to get it back. This used to work on the windows 7 computers I interacted with, but it isn't working on this Windows 10 computer for some reason. Instead, it just opened up a file explorer window without spawning back the taskbar.

How do I get the taskbar back from command line? I'd prefer not to have to restart the device.

Comment: Works for me within my Windows 10 VM.  Can you be more specific other than "it didn't work"?  At this point it seems just easier to reboot the machine.

Comment: I would definitely agree with Ramhound's recommendation:  simply reboot the machine.  That being said, I think that we have vastly different interpretations of what would be *"quite funny."*

Comment: If you are in Europe, then you are in violation of the computer miss use act.

Comment: @richard why? In what way?

Comment: @theonlygusti In that the computer miss use act, says you should not do that sort of thing. There is something about gaining access to another persons computer or account to cause damage. And some other stuff. (IMBO every thing in this act was already covered, adequately, by other legislation).

Comment: @theonlygusti ops typo, no should have been IMHO.

Comment: Downvoters please retract. I don't see anything wrong with this question, and if there is you could at least explain it in the comments.

Comment: @theonlygusti - I will **absolutely** not reverse my vote, unless, you actually improve the quality of your question.  Considering, rebooting the system solves the problem, it doesn't appear you did a proper amount of research before asking this question.  I have started Windows Explorer hundreds of times on Windows 10 after I manually killed it, so in the future provide more specifics other than "it doesn't work".  My downvote had nothing to do with you playing a trick on your friend, it had to do with the quality of your question

Comment: @Ramhound "improve the quality of the question" – you say by doing research. I have done research, I couldn't find anything after a few google searches, so I asked here. Can you find anything after a few google searches? And I am unaware of the specifics I need to provide in order to get a better response, please could you suggest some?

Comment: "you find anything after a few google searches? " - You accepted an answer, that suggested you reboot your machine, which indicates rebooting the machine allowed you to kill Windows Explorer and then launch it from run prompt.

Comment: @Ramhound because apparently it's impossible via any other method, so my hand was forced and it ended up being the solution that worked for me (criteria for accepting answer.) Should I unaccept it?

Comment: @Ramhound please help me

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest @Ramhound's recommendation on rebooting the machine.

You can accomplish this by hitting the **Windows Key + R** (To load up "Run")

Then type this into the window:

```
shutdown /r
```

From there, things ***should*** be back to normal after it finishes rebooting

Comment: This is what I did in between asking this question and now. Why is there no way to get it back otherwise though?

Comment: In theory, running 'explorer.exe' should have brought the process back up.  Although, sometimes these things happen.  Your method was correct, just not the solution this time.

Comment: @theonlygusti: You can also logout and log back in.